# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, asyncio

Выдаёт данную ошибку `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment`. Понимаю, с чем она связна, смотрел документацию Питона и гуглил ответы. однако, всё равно не могу понять как устранить. Аналогичная функция парсит другой тг канал и всё работает отлично, а тут выкидывает это исключение. С чем может быть связано? Если объявлять глобально эту переменную, то на выходе получаю пустой файл, то есть не работает асинхронный цикл и не записывает ничего. Как исправить?

```
async def leaks(message: types.Message):

    msg = []

    async with TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        all_message = client.iter_messages('ссылка на тг канал', reverse=True, offset_date=date)
        async for message in all_message:
            try:
                msg.append(message.message)
                df = pd.DataFrame({'Содержание публикации': [title for title in msg]})
            except Exception:
                pass
    
        df.to_excel('./eaks.xlsx')

        await client.send_file('me', 'leaks.xlsx')
```

Comment: `except Exception: pass` — вот так делать очень вредно

Answer (score 0):

**Вот возможные причины (что нужно иметь ввиду):**

1. Переменная `df` объявлена внутри блока `try/except` - в данном случае переменной `df` просто не будет существовать, если обрабатываемый блок кода выкинет исключение.
2. В смысле глобально? Из данного контекста можно прикинуть что имеется ввиду область до контекстного менеджера, если у вас конечно нет ещё одной `msg` на уровне модуля. Переменная `msg` останется пустой, т.к. её ничто не будет заполнять.

**Небольшой совет по код-стайлу:** оставляйте в блоке `try` ТОЛЬКО тот код, в котором ловится некое исключение, в данном случае возможно одну из 2-х строк можно вынести на строчку выше (зависит от задачи).